# Are resurrection "Save Me" rewards all equally likely?

Tags: temple-run-2

There are 8 resurrection rewards (these are the amounts with "Save Me" fully upgraded) that can come up when spinning the wheel:

- 125 fewest coins
- 250 more coins in a bag
- 625 chest of coins
- 1250 most coins with "X" symbol
- 50 seconds of coin magnet
- 50 seconds of shield
- 1250 meters boost
- 8 gems

Are these all 8 outcomes equally likely?  I haven't collected any data so it would be good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after not getting a response, I did a small study and log the number of times I got various rewards over some 50 resurrections:

- 9 times    125 fewest coins
- 7   times  250 more coins in a bag
- 5    times 625 chest of coins
- 7   times  1250 most coins with "X" symbol
- 6   times  50 seconds of coin magnet
- 7   times  50 seconds of shield
- 9  times   1250 meters boost
- 0  times   8 gems

From this data, not a huge amount, but there was not a single gem reward.  The others appear about all the same likelihood, more or less.  The reason I asked this question was because after the October or November update, it seemed like I wasn't getting the gem reward as often as in earlier versions and my suspicions seem to be confirmed.

Comment: I did notice after I stopped keeping careful track that the gem reward is still possible- about 10 or 15 rewards past when I was keeping track, I got it once.  So it does have a non-zero probability but it seems clearly lower than the others.